# Can I trigger a method on another method call event in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there any thing like onSaveDataMethod.Call like trigger in C#

I do not want to call a method in code directly.

for example:

```
bool save()
{
validate()  // id do not want to call this validate() method
            // it should be called automatically before saving method 

saveRecord();
return true;

}
```

Comment: No, there isn't unless you make one.

Comment: you can get that effect ... but it's a little more complicated... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interceptor_pattern

Comment: using delegate and event is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the answer is **no**, you have to write your own `validation` method.

Comment: i have validate() method, now I want to call this method without calling in the save() method but on save() method call event.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Intercepting Methods](http://doc.postsharp.net/method-interception) with PostSharp. Create aspect (see [more](http://doc.postsharp.net/method-decorator)):

```
using PostSharp.Aspects;
using PostSharp.Serialization;

[PSerializable]
public class ValidationAspect : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        // make you validation here
        validate();
    }
}
```

Apply attribute to your method:

```
[ValidationAspect]
bool save()
{
    saveRecord();
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this assuming you have a base class that all others are inheriting from.  Only the base class will ever know about the internalSave function and all inherited classes will call save and automatically be validated.

Modify member access modifier (protected) on the save function to suit your needs, but leave internalSave as private to avoid calling that function and bypassing the validation.

```
protected bool save(){
   validate(); //Assuming this throws an exception to inform it is not valid
   return internalSave();
}
private bool internalSave(){
    saveRecord();
    return true;
}
```

If you can't have a base class because one already exists that you can't modify, you could also look at using an extension method instead

```
public static class BaseClassNameExtensions
{
   public static bool ValidatedSave(this BaseClassName obj)
   {
       obj.validate(); //again assuming it throws an exception
       return obj.save();
   }
}
```